# Can a faulty motor cause issues to another motor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, motor, stepper-motor, cooling, stepper-driver

This is regarding the circuit of my 3D printer mainboard.

I had an obersvation: It has a cooling fan (40X10 24V) which is having issues lately - it stops working sometimes, and when pushed to rotate, spins back.

Now one of the stepper motors (NEMA 17 ~3.5kgfcm) in my core XY has been malfunctioning, where it misses rotation sometimes out of the blue, which shifts the whole print. I thought this is due to the driver limiting the current to the motor, so I rotated the screw terminal clockwise a bit more to allow more current for the motor. This works fine for a while, but the problem comes back.

Now, I also noticed a few times that this issue occurred when the cooling fan for the drivers stopped working.

Can the stopping of the cooling fan cause the stepper motor to falter?

Comment: Another observation is that the stepper motor which is faltering is placed close to another stepper motor. Although I know stepper motors can work in extreme conditions, can this cause the issue?

Comment: Monitor the motor power supply. Is it stable at the correct voltage?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Brian, excuse my limited knowledge, how do I check the motor's power supply? It's a SMD PCB, so I won't be able to change any connections